# C++ remote key in unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I want to solve the question of removing duplicate lines from a large file, using an `std::unordered_map`, to store a map of whether each line has been encountered previously.

To solve the problem of the file being too large, I want the key in the map to be a `std::string` but **not for it to be stored in memory, instead it's position in file to be the actual stored value**, and then the comparator would just read a line at that position and compare with the current key.

For example, if the string is `"abcd"`, then the key would be `"abcd"` but after determining that it doesn't previously exist in the map, it would be stored as `36` for example, where `36` is the starting position of `"abcd"` in the file.

**Is there any way I can do this using the builtin `std::unordered_map`**(or another hashmap data structure) without implementing my own?

**Also, if there isn't, what's the best way for me to implement it on my own?** I was thinking of using a `std::unordered_map<size_t, vector<int>>`, where the `size_t` key is the `std::hash` of my string and the vector stores the positions in the file, against which I can `readline` and compare. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well no, converting the line to the line number is destructive. To work out where a line has existed before, you'll have to check against each entry in your line num map. If you just use the line as the key, then the checking is automatic.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, but then it would store the entire line after the checking. Can I use line as the key but not store it, perhaps by using a custom comparator or something?

Comment: You can indeed provide custom hash and comparator functors to unordered_map. It sounds trivial. Unclear is why you want a map not unordered_set?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm just checking membership, so `unordered_set` would work as well. My problem is something else, that I can't figure out how to solve using custom hash/comparator. If you have a solution for my problem, please post it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You don't know how to do something ... then read tutorials. StackOverflow is... I don't think it is the correct place to ask that.

Comment: @user202729 When you read tutorials and search on Google and SO and still don't find an answer, as I did, stack overflow is *exactly* the place to ask that. If it's so trivial, please add an answer and I'll accept it if it solves my issue. It's an easy +25 reputation, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have class named `Stuff` whose objects just store `size_t` but that can find out actual text line (like you described):

```
struct Stuff // the naming here is arbitrary and the code illustrative
{
    static WhateverYouNeedToReadRealRata same_to_all_stuff;
    size_t pos;
    std::string getText() const
    {
        return same_to_all_stuff.read_line_somehow_for(pos);
    }
};
```

Then you write custom hasher:

```
struct HashStuff
{
    size_t operator()(Stuff const& stuff) const
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(stuff.getText());
    }
};
```

Then you write custom comparator:

```
struct CompareStuff
{
    bool operator()(Stuff const& left, Stuff const& right) const
    {
        return left.getText() == right.getText();
    }
};
```

So then you can setup your Stuff and instantiate your unordered_set:

```
Stuff::same_to_all_stuff = yourSpecialCase(); 
std::unordered_set<Stuff,HashStuff,CompareStuff> stuffSet;
```

And so Q.E.D. using custom comparator and hasher is trivial?

Comment: Or I could add the `==` operator to Stuff, but yeah, I get the idea. I'm new to C++ std, so I kept missing this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution here in case it helps anybody. This is based on the idea given by `Oo Tiib` in his answer above.

First the two classes, `Line` the represents the line.

```
class Line {
    streampos pos_;
    ifstream &file_;
    mutable streampos tpos_;
    mutable ios_base::iostate state_;

    void SavePos(streampos pos) const {
        tpos_ = file_.tellg();
        state_ = file_.rdstate();
        file_.clear();
        file_.seekg(pos);
    }

    void RestorePos() const {
        file_.setstate(state_);
        file_.seekg(tpos_);
    }
public:
    Line(ifstream &f, streampos pos): pos_(pos), file_(f) { }

    string GetText() const {
        string line;
        SavePos(pos_);
        getline(file_, line);
        RestorePos();
        return line;
    }

    const bool operator==(const Line& other) const {
        return (this->GetText() == other.GetText());
    }
};
```

Then, the `HashLine`, the functor to read the line and hash it string.

```
class HashLine {
public:
    const size_t operator() (const Line& l) const {
        return std::hash<string>()(l.GetText());
    }
};
```

And finally the `rm_dups` function, that creates the hashtable and uses the above classes to remove duplicate lines:

```
int rm_dups(const string &in_file, const string &out_file) {
    string line;
    unordered_set<Line, HashLine> lines;
    ifstream file(in_file);
    ofstream out(out_file);
    if (!file || !out) {
        return -1;
    }
    streampos pos = file.tellg();
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        Line l(file, pos); 
        if (lines.find(l) == lines.end()) {
            // does not exist so far, add this new line
            out << l.GetText() << '\n';
            lines.insert(l);
        }
        pos = file.tellg();
    }
    return 0;
}
```